# How to pass data in Future function to stateful class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use the variable fullName declared in Future getName() async in my stateful class as text as my page loads the name should be displayed on screen in place of value for Text widget Patient, but unable  to do so. Tried different options but no success yet.

```
class PatientDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PatientDashboardState createState() => _PatientDashboardState();
}

Future getName() async {
  var id = "26"; 
  var url = baseurl + patientData + id;
  var data;
  var rest;  
    print('Calling uri: $url');
    // 4
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    // 5
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = response.body;
      // rest = data['result'] as List;
      // print(rest);
      //print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(data);
    // var name = user['result']['name'];
    String fullName = user['result'][0][0];
    
    print("Name: ${fullName}"); 
}

class _PatientDashboardState extends State<PatientDashboard> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getName();
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                    return
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                          Text("Patient",
                              //'${widget.patientId}',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontSize: 34.0))
                        ],
                      ),
  
    
  }
```

Comment: Your `getName` method doesn't return anything. I think you forgot to return the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PatientDashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PatientDashboardState createState() => _PatientDashboardState();
}

class _PatientDashboardState extends State<PatientDashboard> {

String fullName;

Future getName() async {
  var id = "26"; 
  var url = baseurl + patientData + id;
  var data;
  var rest;  
    print('Calling uri: $url');
    // 4
    http.Response response = await http.get(url);
    // 5
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      data = response.body;
      // rest = data['result'] as List;
      // print(rest);
      //print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(data);
    // var name = user['result']['name'];
    setState({
       fullName = user['result'][0][0];
    });
    
    print("Name: ${fullName}"); 
}



  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getName();
  }
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                    return
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Welcome',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
                          Text("Patient ${widget.patientId}",                   
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                  fontSize: 34.0))
                        ],
                      ),
  
    
  }
```

Or else you can use like

```
Future<String> getName() async{
   ....
   ....
   return user['result'][0][0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution helped me in the problem.                                                                                                                                                    I have added a return statement like this 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theFuture = getName();
    theFuture.then((value){
      return value;});                                                                                                                               making the function Future<String> getName() async. How can I use the return value in my Text Widget?

Comment: @Samneer Check out [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: Sure I will look into this

Comment: Hey @Sameer please upvote the question too if it helped you